# android how to take picture only use system camera

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE )
```

this intent will show a list of cameras to choose if i've installed other camera apps, so my question is how to directly call system camera, not to choose others.

Comment: i find it's difficult to direct call system camera app, because different roms have different camera activity name. i found some roms camera activity below:      //com.google.android.gallery3d-com.android.camera.CameraActivity | galaxy nexus
       //com.sec.android.app.camera-com.sec.android.app.camera.Camera | galaxy s3
       //com.android.hwcamera-com.android.hwcamera.Camera | huawei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

```
Intent camIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        Intent systemCamIntent = new Intent(camIntent);
        systemCamIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.sec.android.app.camera", "com.sec.android.app.camera.Camera"));
        startActivity(systemCamIntent);
```

You can get list of camera by using the code below, then you should create a logic to understand which is system camera for different rooms.

```
List<Intent> yourIntentsList = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(camIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {           
            finalIntent = new Intent(camIntent);
            finalIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            yourIntentsList.add(finalIntent);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, actually now i just handle like this.